# Javascript code shown when I share a link to website on facebook

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

When sharing some links on facebook(either programatically or manually), javascript code is being shown in the post.

Thus my question is more related to how to fix my website, so that, when posting link to facebook, javascript code doesn't show in the facebook post.

Forexample try posting this link:
http://djuice.com.pk/discounts

You'l see javascript code(which is present on the shared page) in the facebook post.
[image]

Comment: Most probably because the page is full of errors and warnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are should set `description` param for sharing button. For example:

```
 FB.ui(
      {
       method: 'feed',
       name: 'The Facebook SDK for Javascript',
       caption: 'Bringing Facebook to the desktop and mobile web',
       description: (
          'A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +
          'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' +
          'social graph and distribution power to your site.'
       ),
       link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/',
       picture: 'http://www.fbrell.com/public/f8.jpg'
      },
      function(response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
          alert('Post was published.');
        } else {
          alert('Post was not published.');
        }
      }
    );
```

Comment: Yes, but in that case, the description would be hardcoded in my code. I am sure there is some way of adding description on my html page, which can be read by facebook.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in this case the description is taken from the meta description

Comment: But if you do not help, show how you connect this function to the site. So it will be clearer what the problem